# C# MVC Query with WHERE clause and 2 params from the View

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to query my database with a WHERE clause and pass to parameters from my view to the controller. I am at a total loss as I am a JavaScript and PHP developer and am currently learning dotnet MVC (I am using vs10 framework4).

I need to in essence make this query:

```
select * from myTable where column1=16 and column2=24
```

The values of column1 and column2 are in my View.  I have found a million examples on how to pull either a whole table, or a result based upon one parameter, I cannot figure out how to do that simple query.

This seems like a simple task and I would appreciate any help as I have spent 5 hours trying to figure this out.

Here are some key components of my code that will hopefully help someone help me.  I sincerely appreciate any help.

Controller:

```
    public class SignBuilderController : Controller
    {


        SignBuilderModel signBuilderModel = new SignBuilderModel();


        //
        // Initialize database entities
        SignBuilderEntities _db;
        public SignBuilderController()
        {
            _db = new SignBuilderEntities();
        }

 //
        // Get /SignBuilder/PrintSetup
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult PrintSetup()
        {

            var pricesList = signBuilderModel.GetPricingList().ToList();
            return View("PrintSetup", pricesList);

        }



// get Column1 and column 2 query
public ActionResult TestPage(int column1, int column1) 
{
     //do something here
     return View();
}
```

And in my View I would retrieve the values for my where clause from input fields.
Example:

```
<input type="text" name="column1value" id="column1value" />
<input type="text" name="column2value" id="column2value" />
```

Obviously I am using a Model as well, so if that is needed to make this work no problem.  I am really looking for sample code I can use as an example to learn from.  I really appreciate any help, and am about to pull out my hair.

Comment: MVC doesn't really factor into it as I understand? Are you asking how to get column1, column2 in your action method, or how to use them to query a database? If its the first, change from name="columnxvalue" to name="columnx" to match your action parameters. If its the second, there are alot of options. Some of them is using SqlConnection(included in framework), or something like NHibernate.

Comment: basically, I will use ajax to pass my values to a new view.. then I want to query the database with those two values.  So I guess what I need to know is how to use querystring values in my controller's sql query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this(I assume your view is strongly typed):

```
public ActionResult(int column1, int column2)      
{
   //do something here.          
     var model = 
        (
            from p in this.GetPricingList()
            where (p.column1 == column1) && (p.column2 == column2)
            select p
        ).FirstOrDefault();
     return View(model);     
}
```

and in the View:

```
<input type="text" name="column1" id="column1value"  value="<%=Model.column1%>"/> 
<input type="text" name="column2" id="column2value"  value="<%=Model.column2%>"/>
```

Comment: This worked.. But I had to change (p.column1 = column1) &&... to p.column1 == column1      p.column2 == column 2      On two separate lines and no parenthesis.. thanks Cypernate, a life-saver.

Answer (score 2):

You need to post the values to the Action method on your controller

Using something like this in your view:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("RunQuery", "ControllerName")) { %>

    <input type="text" name="column1" id="column1value" />
    <input type="text" name="column2" id="column2value" />
    <input type="submit" value="Run Query" />

<% } %>
```

and then the accompanying action method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RunQuery(string column1, string column2)
{
    var results = GetDataFromDatabase(column1, column2);
    return View(results ); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This works, but I am using AJAX.. But you answered a later question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid your code would not compile. What you annotated as your controller does not inherit from controller class at all and your actionresult method has no name. I wonder how could you visit your page in the browser. The code should be like

```
public class MyApplicationModel:Controller
{

    //use entity framework
    private MyApplicationEntities entities = new MyApplicationEntities();

    //
    // Method to query database for price lists table
    public IQueryable<pricingUploaded> GetPricingList()
    {
        return entities.pricingUploadeds;
    }  

    // 
    // Method to query Column1 and Column2 in table pricingUploaded
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Query()
    {
       //this action will render the page the first time
       return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]//this method will only accept posted requests
    public ActionResult Query(int column1, int column2) 
    {
         //do something here.
         var _result = entities.Where(x=>x.column1 == column1 && x.column2 == column2);
         return View(_result);//pass result to strongly typed view
    }
```

In your view you have to create a form, that when submitted can post values to HttpPost overload of Query method

```
<%:Html.BeginForm();%>
<input type="text" name="column1">
<input type="text" name="column2">
<input type="submit" id="save" value="query">
<%:Html.EndForm();%>
```

Now you enter values in your form and click query button, you will have column1 and column2 values in you Query Actionresult accepting posted request. You better put a break point there and inspect how things are really working and figure out how to do what you need to do.

**Edit:** based on your comment that you want to pass values ajaxically you can do little bit of jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
   $("form").submit(function(){
       $.ajax({
              type:"post",
              url:"myapplicationmodel/query",
              success:function(data)
             {
                  //do something with returned data
             }
              });
return false;// to prevent normal form post
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the entities is a `Linq to Entity` right? if that is the case, couldn't you use:

```
var model = from e in entities
            where column1=16 and column2=24
            select e;
```

and then pass that model into the vew.

Basically, if `entities` is of the type `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable` or any of the other linq-able interfaces, you can perform that type of query.  Make sure that you are `using System.Linq;` in the top of your code file.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok :) Let me know! Also, `model` variable will be a list containing all of the returned values.  If you only want one value, use the `.FirstOrDefault();` as Cybernate suggested.  But if you want to display a list of results, then send that as your model and use the List template for the view.  Let me know if you'd like some help making it work in the view!  MVC can be a beast some times

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
public ActionResult(int column1, int column2) 
{
     var query = from m in _db.MyTable
                  where m.Column1 == column1
                  where m.Column2 == column2
                  select m;
                  // Or this for typed model
                  // select new MyModel { Column1 = m.Column1, etc }

     var model = query.First();

     return View(model);
}
```